# Delete columns in a matrix with value 0 when all cols are not numeric

Tags: r, matrix

I have a large matrix with +5000 columns that look like this:

```
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d5559 d5560  d5561
R1  0  3  4  0     9  grey simone
R1  0  2  2  0     7  blue   Emma
R1  0  1  2  0     4  grey simone
R1  0  3  2  0     8   red Evelyn
```

I wish to delete all columns with 0. I know how to do this when the matrix contain only numeric columns:

```
mymatrix[, which(colSums(mymatrix) != 0)]
```

but this does not work when there are non-numeric columns. How to proceed with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have matrix it can have only one class so all the numbers would also turn into characters if you have any non-numeric element in it. In that case, you can do

```
mymatrix[, colSums(mymatrix != "0") != 0]

#     d1   d3  d4  d5559 d5560  d5561   
#[1,] "R1" "3" "4" "9"   "grey" "simone"
#[2,] "R1" "2" "2" "7"   "blue" "Emma"  
#[3,] "R1" "1" "2" "4"   "grey" "simone"
#[4,] "R1" "3" "2" "8"   "red"  "Evelyn"
```

Or other way around

```
mymatrix[, colSums(mymatrix == "0") == 0]
```

---

You can also use `apply` column-wise with same logic

```
mymatrix[, apply(mymatrix != "0", 2, any)]
```

and

```
mymatrix[, !apply(mymatrix == "0", 2, all)]
```

**data**

```
mymatrix <- structure(c("R1", "R1", "R1", "R1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", 
"2", "1", "3", "4", "2", "2", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "9", "7", 
"4", "8", "grey", "blue", "grey", "red", "simone", "Emma", "simone", 
"Evelyn"), .Dim = c(4L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("d1", "d2", 
"d3", "d4", "d5", "d5559", "d5560", "d5561")))
```

Comment: I'll give you odds of $1.01 that `mymatrix` isn't a `matrix`

Comment: Sigh...I think so too. :/ I guess this should still work on dataframes.

Comment: You´re certainly right - it was in fact originally a matrix, but I stupidly forgot that it got converted into a data frame (the above format) by addition of some non-numeric extra rows/identifiers on just the one side. Anyway, it did indeed work on a data frame, too. Thanks (and yes, I did upvote).

Answer (score 1):

We can subset the first row and check if the columns are numeric or not

```
i1 <- sapply(type.convert(as.list(mymatrix[1,])), is.numeric)
```

and then identify the columns to remove

```
mymatrix[, setdiff(colnames(mymatrix), names(which(!colSums(mymatrix[, i1] != 0))))]
#    d1   d3  d4  d5559 d5560  d5561   
#[1,] "R1" "3" "4" "9"   "grey" "simone"
#[2,] "R1" "2" "2" "7"   "blue" "Emma"  
#[3,] "R1" "1" "2" "4"   "grey" "simone"
#[4,] "R1" "3" "2" "8"   "red"  "Evelyn"
```

---

Or we can use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(mymatrix) %>% 
  type.convert %>%
   select_if(~ is.numeric(.) && any(. != 0)| !is.numeric(.))
```

#### data

```
mymatrix <- structure(c("R1", "R1", "R1", "R1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "3", 
"2", "1", "3", "4", "2", "2", "2", "0", "0", "0", "0", "9", "7", 
"4", "8", "grey", "blue", "grey", "red", "simone", "Emma", "simone", 
"Evelyn"), .Dim = c(4L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("d1", "d2", 
"d3", "d4", "d5", "d5559", "d5560", "d5561")))
```